# XRegExp and unicode

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, xregexp

I'm a newbie and I can't start working with XRegExp, there should be some silly mistake, but I can't find it.

```
<script src="xregexp-all-v4.0.0.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script>
  let str = "aābḇ";
  let reg = XRegExp( '\\p{L}' , 'gu' );
  console.log( XRegExp.replace (str, reg, "$&|") );
</script>
```

**Output:** `a|Ä|b|á|¸‡`

Comment: I ran it with XRegExp 3.1.1 and 3.2.0 and it outputs `a|ā|b|ḇ|`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've tried 3.2.0 and the result is the same. I guess, I miss some encoding settings in html, right?

Comment: Yeah, it is not a regex problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But could you tell me, what encoding settings I should add?

Comment: Solved! added `<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>`